# Element type error being observed

Tags: abaqus

I am using C3D8R element and creating section points across elements. However when doing it, I get the below error

"ELEMENT TYPE C3D8R HAS NO OUTPUT AT SECTION POINT 1.  SECTION POINT REMOVED"

Can anyone let me know how should i address this error?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken section points are only associated with beam, shells, layered elements, etc.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Yes... I am creating a solid element C3D8R

Comment: i mean why are you trying to create section points on a solid element?

Comment: I have created the section points for shell elements(S8R) and trying to replicate the same for solid element. When creating for solid elements, I get the above error. Could you please let me know if its possible to create section points for solid elements as I dont find any information regarding the same for solid elements or How can i address this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define section points in this way for solid elements such as C3D8R, since they use a completely different formulation. Casual reading of the documentation will make that clear.

However, you can discretize 3D geometry using "continuum shell" elements (in Abaqus: SC6R, SC8R). These elements have displacement DOF only and the thickness is defined by the nodal geometry directly. You should be sure to read the docs and become familiar with their usage before trusting your analysis results.

As far as I'm aware, you can define continuum shell element section properties in the same way as for conventional shell elements, with a couple of caveats. For example, you cannot specify an offset for the reference surface from the element midsurface when the section properties are specified by one or more material layers.